# Javascript not working for: onclick show hidden div from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to allow a user to click in a textarea and when they start typing it shows an initially hidden div.   Here is my script and html, but this does not work, not sure where I am going wrong.

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("showPanel").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("thePanel").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<textarea name="showPanel" rows="2" cols="35" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:300px; height:50px;"></textarea>
<div id="thePanel" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:100px;width:300px;height:200px;background: red; visibility:hidden;">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `showPanel` element doesn't exist at the time that your script runs. Move the script down below the last `div`, before the `</body>`.

Comment: showPanel is a `name`, not an `id`.

Comment: ...also, the `textarea` has no id. A `name` is not an `id`. There's a reason why they're to separate attributes. There's also a reason why `getElementById` is named the way it is. It fetches by the element's `id`, not by its `name`.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this post got voted down? I realize I am not an awesome coder and my script was messed up, thus the need to post on here to get a correction. I would imagine others could learn from a failed script and how to correct it from this post.  Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some minor changes based on what the guys have commented on above.

- Added an id to the `textarea`
- Moved JS script so that the the elements exist before you call the JS.

  ```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <textarea name="showPanel" id="showPanel" rows="2" cols="35" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:300px; height:50px;"></textarea>
       <div id="thePanel" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:100px;width:300px;height:200px;background: red; visibility:hidden;">
       </div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("showPanel").onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("thePanel").style.visibility = "visible";
          }
       </script>

    </body>

  </html>
  ```

Comment: posting in a bunch of code without an explanation...no bueno!

Comment: Yes, now this all makes sense and I see exactly where I was going wrong.  Thank you all for your suggestions and help!